# where does webpack cache its work for rebuilding?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

This page shows a lot of compilation modes for webpack, and some of them *rebuild* faster than they *build*.

[image]

I am trying to measure the speed of different build-tools, but I can't figure out if I am *building* or *rebuilding*.  I mean.. what files do I have to clear to make sure that I am rebuilding?  Just the target directory?  Or is there another cache somewhere?

For example is the second build here a build or a rebuild the second time?

```
node_modules/.bin/webpack --output-path ~/target
rm -r target
node_modules/.bin/webpack --output-path ~/target
```

if that *rebuilds*, what to I have to clear to make it *build* again?

and does the second one here *build* or *rebuild*?

```
node_modules/.bin/webpack --output-path ~/target
node_modules/.bin/webpack --output-path ~/target
```

And if that is another *build*, what do I have to do to *rebuild*?

(webpack 4)

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR:** "rebuild" only happens during [`watch` mode](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/) or [`development` mode](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/#mode-development).

### Webpack

Webpack doesn't seem to cache to a file, but only in memory.

> ### cache
>
> Cache the generated webpack modules and chunks to improve build speed. Caching will be automatically enabled by default while in watch mode and webpack is set to mode development.

[Webpack docs | cache options](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#cache)

Since it's only enabled in development & watch mode by default, each of your command should be a fresh build. You can either turn off this `cache` options to be sure, or specifically target `production`:

```
node_modules/.bin/webpack --output-path ~/target --mode=production
```

---

I run into this question right after checking out the new changes in webpack 5, one of which was to [allow caching to a local file](https://github.com/webpack/changelog-v5/blob/master/README.md#changes-to-the-structure).

> `cache`: Object removed: Setting to a memory-cache object is no longer possible
>
> `cache.type` added: It's now possible to choose between "memory" and "filesystem"

I take it that it means that currently in webpack 4 it's not possible to have cache in filesystem.

---

**Edit**: You didn't mention it in the question, but I saw just now you mentioned `babel` in the reasoning for the bounty.

### Babel

If you use `babel-loader`, there's a `cacheDirectory` option that's `false` by default. However, if enabled, the default directory is in `node_modules/.cache/babel-loader`.

Here's the snippet about it in the docs, emphasis mine:

> `cacheDirectory`: Default false. When set, the given directory will be used to cache the results of the loader. **Future webpack builds will attempt to read from the cache to avoid needing to run the potentially expensive Babel recompilation process on each run**. If the value is set to true in options `({cacheDirectory: true})`, the loader will use the default cache directory in `node_modules/.cache/babel-loader` or fallback to the default OS temporary file directory if no `node_modules` folder could be found in any root directory.

[babel-loader options](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/#options)